# Problemas para abrir diferentes modal con html y jquery

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap, modal

Tengo un switch jquery en el cual si se cumplen las condiciones tiene que abrir un modal diferente.

**Problema:** El problema esta en que solo me abre el primer modal de forma correcta y los demás solo se oscurece la pantalla.

> Anexo parte del código, ya que el proyecto en si es PHP.

```
 <!-- Modal Usuario -->
    <div class="modal" id="editarUsuario" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Titulo Modal -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5>Editar Usuario</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Formulario -->
                <form>
                   <!--Nombre de usuario-->
                   <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-md">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-group-md" id="username" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--Contraseña-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-md">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-group-md" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña" alt="Nombre del titular." >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--Nombre de empleado-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-md">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-group-md" id="nombre_empleado" placeholder="Nombre del Empleado">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-md">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></span>
                                    <select id="select-rol" class="form-control">
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="0" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  switch (tabla) {
            case "usuarios":
                $("#editarUsuario").modal();
                break;
            case "conductores":
                $("#editarConductores").modal();
                break;
            case "proveedores":
            alert("P");

            $("#exampleModalCenter").modal();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: intenta agregándole el "show" ej: $("#miModal").modal("show");

Comment: @JuanCarlos le he agregado el `.modal('show')` y tengo el mismo problema

Comment: @JuanCarlos le he agregado el `.modal('show')` y tengo el mismo problema

Comment: Este es tu html original? donde seleccionas el modal? Como lo selecciones?

Comment: @BlackSheep es un `html` el cual utiliza `bootstrap` y obtengo los datos al hacer click en diferentes tablas, la idea es que me abra el modal correspondiente a cada una de las tablas a utilizar

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la parte de los botones en donde se hace clic para que se abra el modal?, al igual que tu función completa en donde se encuentra tu switch, ya que no sabemos ni que valor tiene `tabla`